# Using T in a baseFragment, will result in using that function to need a 'Nothing" instead of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, parcelable, super

This is my method:

```
abstract class BaseFragmentKey<T : Fragment> : Parcelable {
     fun newFragment(): T {
        val fragment = createFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable("KEY", this)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }

    protected abstract fun createFragment(): T

    @CallSuper
    open fun updateExistingFragment(fragment: T): T {
        return fragment
    }
}
```

But when I try to call with a Fragment:

```
   newFragment = newKey.updateExistingFragment(existingFragment)
```

It says before compiling that `Type mismatch. Required Nothing, found Fragment`. If I do `existingFragment as Nothing` it crashes cause I cannot cast to null.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you attach `newKey` implementation?

Comment: neyKey is a : BaseFragmentKey (I already attached it's code)

Comment: but you cannot just instantiate `BaseFragmentKey` you have to at least set type parameter `T`. That's why I'm asking

Comment: Attached pic from where I call updateExistingFragment. Item that I try, is Fragment

Comment: the problem in wildcard in `stateChange.getNewState<BaseFragmentKey<*>>`. It should be for example `stateChange.getNewState<BaseFragmentKey<Fragment>>`

Comment: You are totally right, changing from there the * to Fragment works, thanks a lot!!!
If you make an answer regarding this, I will accept it, so the credit and points can go to you

Comment: ok, thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in wildcard in `stateChange.getNewState<BaseFragmentKey<*>>`. It should be for example `stateChange.getNewState<BaseFragmentKey<Fragment>>`